# Mixing Galera and MariaDB/MySQL replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera

reading about it online, it appears we can use both Galera replication and native MariaDB/MySQL replication together. Can anyone confirm that this is correct?

I'm thinking of a scenario where Data Center A has 3 Galera nodes synchronously replicating with each other, and Data Center B also has 3 Galera nodes synchronously replicating with each other. Then between one node in Data Center A and one node in Data Center B we have MariaDB/MySQL asyncoronous replication, in master-master configuration so going both ways.

As I understand it we now have:

- Nice fast clusters for reads and writes in both data centers, which have redundancy within themselves if one node goes down.
- Redundancy between data centers, so even if all of A or all of B goes down the other data center will stay functioning.
- Under normal circumstances all nodes in both data centers have consistent data, or will within milliseconds of each other.

Have I missed anything - any potential problems? Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

- `AUTO_INCREMENT` is probably not usable.
- `UNIQUE` need care to avoid accidental dups.

How far apart (in ms) are the datacenters?

Comment: AUTO_INCREMENT is already a concern for simple MySQL replication between two servers, and is solved using `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset`. In my example above `auto_increment_increment` would be 6, and each server would have a different `auto_increment_offset`. Would there be any reason that wouldn't work here?

Let's say in this hypothetical scenario the data centers are 20ms apart. What implications might this have?

Comment: @DavidCunningham -- I expect Galera would insist on auto_increment_increment being 3.  That is, if you set it to 6, it will change it to 3.  Furthermore, if you take a node out of a cluster (or it crashes), the incr will be changed to 2?

Comment: Regardless, you should set up a testbed with, say 6 VMs on one machine -- to see what happens.

Comment: If Galera automatically changes the auto_increment_increment that could be a problem, since the cluster will be bigger than it realises. We'll have to test it, and testing is certainly something we'll do. I was checking to see if anyone else had used the above scenario and had experience to share.

Comment: I note Galera has a wsrep_auto_increment_control option we can disable to control the auto_increment_increment and auto_increment_offset manually.